# Django Forms: How to reference existing object field values in form validation?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

So I am creating a Django app which I hope will be used in my school. This means that I have users that are teachers and students, and different permissions for these accounts. I have set it up so that every accounts has a self.teacher attribute, which is a boolean. So for students accounts, self.teacher will be False, and for teachers, self.teacher will be True.

My app also contains a profile page, and this page has an edit profile feature. In my app, I want the user to be able to edit, amongst other things, their grade. Now, I have it set up so that grade can be an option of:
- 10
- 11
- 12
- N/A
Students must only be able to pick a number, while teachers are allowed to select N/A. So I want to have a form validation (which validates the grade field) that checks to see if the user submitting the form is a student, and if so, checks that they have not selected N/A. If they have selected N/A, the validation should raise an error.

Any thoughts on how to implement this using Django Forms?

Comment: The Django auth app ships with groups. You can use that to set different permissions for teachers and students. While you might have a need to build a group/permissions thing from scratch, I highly recommend using what Django has already done for you. You can read more about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want students to select a given value (here: 'N/A'), the best way is to remove this value from the choice list. In the `__init__` method of the form, checks if the form instance is a student or not, and if so, remove the 'N/A' value from the choice list.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about how I can check in the __init__ method? How do I reference the .teacher field of the object in the __init__method? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If you want me to be more specific, please be yourself more verbose by giving the code of your form.